# Selenium C# Webdriver: I am getting error: 'iWebDriver' does not contain definition for 'WaitforElement'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to Selenium and C#... I am in middle of a selenium application development using C#. I have a drop down menu on a webpage. I want selenium to click on the exact name after clicking the drop down menu. So I did something like this:

**C#/NUnit code:**

`driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("z")).Click;
driver.WaitForElement(By.LinkText("xxxxx"));
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("xxxxx")).Click();`

but when I build my code I get the following error:

> 'iWebDriver' does not contain definition for 'WaitforElement'

Comment: hi, you don't have to wait for an element explicitly, you just use implicit wait, it will wait until element appears, so your second line is not necessary.

Comment: Can you please offer an example?

Comment: I have created an answer below, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can offer you an example, but I don't know c#, But I can give you the example from **Ruby Selenium Binding.**

```
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait=20
driver.find_element(:link_text,"z").click; 
driver.find_element(:link_text,"xxxxx").click
```

Since I have given the implicit wait 20, whenever it finds the element via `find_element` function, it waits for 20 minutes, So your external wait statement is not necessary .

**The C# code might be(I don't know C#, I took it from the net and placing it here)**

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("z")).Click;
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("xxxxx")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work the way you shown.

The next code is an example how you should write it:

```
WebDriverWait watiDriver = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = watiDriver.Until(x => Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("")));
```

Where `Driver` is your instance of a webdriver.

If you want to use it as you shown then you need to add an extension method to the webdriver class. To do this, just create a new static class (with any name) and insert the next code into it:

```
public static IWebElement WaitForElement(this IWebDriver driver, By how)
{
     webDriverWait watiDriver = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
     return watiDriver.Until(x => Driver.FindElement(FindElement(how));
}
```

Comment: @Geezus mark the answer if you think it's the best.)